# Getting table2 Info from foreign key in table1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What query could work to get whole data of table1 & table2 using a foreign key that table1 has ?

I got in table1

username
password
person_id (Foreign key)

And in table2

id
name
last_name
address

I need a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.username='$var' && table1.password = '$var' 
&& "table1.person_id = table2.id"
```

(this is the part that i dont know) ~ And i know this is a very unsecure query

Sorry for the noob question , im using mysqli functions and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `JOIN`, specifically an `INNER JOIN`. What a `JOIN` does is match records from one table to another based upon some conditions. So what you would be wanting is

```
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        table1
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.person_id = table2.id
    WHERE 
        table1.username='$var' 
        AND table1.password = '$var';
```

Take a look at [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) site for an explanation on joins.

Answer (score 0):

You are blending too much PHP with your SQL, and your query uses outdated syntax  for joins

You would want your query to look more like this

```
"SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2 
JOIN table2 ON table1.person_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.username='$var' 
AND table1.password = '$var'"
```

Since you tagged this as mysqli, if you want to use this with mysqli connections, you would connect to your database with something like this:

```
$dbc = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if  ($dbc->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2 
JOIN table2 ON table1.person_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.username='$var' 
AND table1.password = '$var'";
```

And then call it like  so

```
$dbc->query($query);
```

You would get your variables likely either through `POST` (from a form) or `GET` variables.

Example:

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
```

where `var` is a named input field in your HTML form, like

```
<input type="text" name="var" />
```

Of course this is just a beginning.   I hope I'm not answering too much.

**Edit:**  Note, if you are looking to do this in a more secure way, here's how to do the same query (making it two variables) using prepared statements:

```
$query = $dbc->("SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1, table2 
JOIN table2 ON table1.person_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.username=? 
AND table1.password = ?");

$query->bind_param("ss",$var1,$var2);
$query->execute();
```

and then you can call the items from your select and bind them into variables like so:

```
$query->bind_results($col1, $col2);
```

Then close the query

```
$query->close();
```

Note the `"ss"` in the `bind_param` designates that both variables are strings.  If it's an integer, use `i`

(and of course I carry on a bit):

To call those variables you can just do

```
while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo $col1;
    echo $col2;

}
```

but I digress...